# Slack Sign In Button + Maximum app integrations. How does it work?

Tags: slack-api

I have an Slack application that I allow some people to integrate to their Slack workspace using the 'Sign in with Slack'-button I configured: https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack

However, I read that a free workspace channel can only integrate a maximum of 10 custom apps: https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/115002422943-Message-file-storage-and-app-limits-on-the-Free-plan

Does that mean that only 10 people could sign in, authorize, integrate and use the bot, or is the same bot considered to be one single app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You app is always counted as one and the maximum app limitation is counted against the number of different apps installed into one workspace.

So if other workspaces are installing your app it will count against **their** limit (if they are on a free plan). But not your own.

Also, if an app is installed into the same workspace multiple times (different users can install the same app) it is still counted as one app against the limit.

Comment: Thank you Erik. The last sentence is what I really needed to know!

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer solved your question please consider marking it as solution by clicking on the checkmark. TY.